# Unable to perform any action before Process.Runtime.exec statement line

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec

my very first post here after long time of searching but yet get an answer regarding this issue, please help me in this issue.

I am using Netbean 6.9.1 to build a Java application which massive call to few different external program, therefore I used process and runtime function to call for external program.

The whole application process is separated into few stages and I wish to inform the user till which stage the application is currently running by updating the GUI textarea, the code is showed as below:

public void executeCommand (String cmd, File path)
    {

```
    try
    {
        ****areaOutput.setText("Executing audio decoding, please wait till process is done\n");****  
        btnTranscribe.setEnabled(false);
        areaOutput.setEditable(false);
        areaOutput.setEnabled(false);
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd , null, path);
        InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        System.out.println("<ERROR>");
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println("</ERROR>");
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
        areaOutput.append("\n\nConversion is done, processing with features extraction....");
    } catch (Throwable t)
      {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }

}
```

As showed in the code above, I wish to set the Textarea and disable some button before executing the command, but when the application ran, all of these line seems unable to work and nothing is changed at the application itself till the command is finish executed, any solution to run the pre-command code execute first before the .exec() start to run?

I appreciate your great help and advice regarding this issue.

Best regards,
Striky

P/S:

hi there, I have make a Thread class for this CmdExec in order to execute cmd in different thread:

```
     public class CmdExec extends Thread
     {
 private String cmd;
     private File path;

      public CmdExec() {
      }

      public CmdExec(String cmd, File path) {
  this.cmd = cmd;
  this.path = path;
      }

      public void run(){

  try
    {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd , null, path);
        InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        System.out.println("<ERROR>");
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
        System.out.println("</ERROR>");
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
    } catch (Throwable t)
      {
        t.printStackTrace();
      }
```

}
    }

and in order to call to this class,

CmdExec tryDemo = new CmdExec();
        tryDemo = new CmdExec(strSegment, fSegment);
        tryDemo.run(); 
is used to start the thread, but I failed to put SwingUtilities.invokeLater in any part of these process, it simply won't run the tryDemo.run() because it is void...

Also, may I know so far am I doing right?? Very thank you for your kind help regarding this issue

P/S 2: I have just added another runnable code (so threads for process executing, runnable to GUI update) for GUI update command as below:

```
            Runnable doWorkRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
    System.out.println("hello world");
    btnTranscribe.setEnabled(false);
    areaOutput.setEditable(false);
    areaOutput.setEnabled(false);
    areaOutput.setText("Performing segmentation, please wait till process is done\n"); }
};
```

and I used SwingUtilies.invokeLater before the execution of process as below:

```
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doWorkRunnable);
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd , null, path);
```

But all these failed, am I get the wrong sequence for the GUI and process thread coordination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are executing this work on the EDT (the thread which updates the gui).  so, the gui cannot update until all this work finishes.  what you want to do is run a separate thread which does all the work and periodically calls SwingUtilities.invokeLater with a status update.

Comment: so you mean basically I will need to create a thread and put this execute method inside the thread?

Comment: pretty much.  only the process launching and handling goes in the other thread.  then you use the SwingUtilities.invokeLater method to interact with the EDT thread (other threads may not interact directly with the gui).

Comment: hihi, I have made a thread for all this CmdExec process, I have put the latest code on top of the main content, and in order to call to this class,

CmdExec tryDemo = new CmdExec(); 
tryDemo = new CmdExec(strSegment, fSegment); 
tryDemo.run(); 

is used to start the thread, but I failed to put SwingUtilities.invokeLater in any part of these process, it simply won't run the tryDemo.run() because it is void...

Also, may I know so far am I doing right?? Very thank you for your kind help regarding this issue

Comment: HI again, I have just added another runnable code (so threads for process executing, runnable to GUI update) for GUI update command as showed in P/S 2 above, and I used SwingUtilies.invokeLater before the execution of process as below:

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doWorkRunnable);
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd , null, path);
But all these failed, am I get the wrong sequence for the GUI and process thread coordination?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put sleep before execute method. To verify what is happening.

Comment: Hi there, thank for the replies =). I have put Thread.sleep in front of the execute method, but the GUI still failed to update >.<